# How to fix 'Not getting SignInWithgoogle property in Flutter"

Tags: dart, flutter

I was i just playing with google sign authentication,
so I didnt getting the SignInWithGoogle property.
I will show some code screenshot down there.

```
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {

  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = new GoogleSignIn();

  Future<FirebaseUser> _signIn() async {
    GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication = await googleSignInAccount
        .authentication;

    FirebaseUser user = await _auth
  }
}
```

I supposed to get signinwithgoogle property after auth.
which i didnt get.

Answer (score 0):

be sure about you enable google sign in from your firebaseAuth console,
[image]

[google_sign_in](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_sign_in#-readme-tab-)(version : **google_sign_in: ^4.0.1+3**) as package provides in the example you should be sign-in with bellow code

```
final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

  Future<void> _handleSignIn() async {
    try {
      await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since 0.7.0 version of FirebaseAuth package, there is no `googleSignIn` method: [CHANGELOG](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_auth#-changelog-tab-)

If you are using new version, you have to use `_auth.signInWithCredential` method:

```
final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

Future<FirebaseUser> _handleSignIn() async {
  final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
  final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;

  final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
    accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
    idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
  );

  final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
  print("signed in " + user.displayName);
  return user;
}
```